# Give an example of two subsets $X,Y$ of the real line such that $\overline{X\cap Y}\neq \bar X \cap \bar Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Give an example of two subsets $X,Y$ of the real line such that $\overline{X\cap Y}\neq \bar X \cap \bar Y$.

### My Attempt

$X=(0,1)$
$Y=(1,2)$

Is this right? What can I say about it?

Comment: What do you think you can say about it?

Comment: Do you mean union on both sides or intersection on both sides? Otherwise it's quite trivial...

Comment: intersections on both sides sorry ill edit

Answer (score 7):

Let $X=\mathbb{Q}$, and $Y=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$. Since we know that $X$ and $Y$ are dense over $\mathbb{R}$,  then $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}=\mathbb{R}$. Then, we have $\overline{X\cap
Y}=\emptyset$, and $\overline{X}\cap \overline{Y}=\mathbb{R}$.

Your solution is also right. Let $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=(1,2)$. Then, we have $\overline{X}=[0,1]$ and $\overline{Y}=[1,2]$. Then, we have $\overline{X\cap
Y}=\emptyset$, and $\overline{X}\cap \overline{Y}=\{1\}$.

Either, way we are looking at two disjoint set $X$ and $Y$ that their closure intersects is not empty.

Comment: I had a typo, must prove with intersection on both sides

Comment: It will be just fine. The Solution holds for intersections.